# How to install vim.full in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I've installed Ubuntu Server but I have only `vim.basic`?

How do i install `vim.full`?

Tried with `aptitude install vim` but it said it's always installed.

Because `vim` is a soft link to `vim.basic`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the `vim-nox` package if you do not need a GUI, else try `vim-gnome` or `vim-gtk`. There are a number of vim packages compiled with different feature-sets:

```
% apt-cache search vim | grep vim-
jvim-canna - Japanized VIM (Canna version)
jvim-doc - Documentation for jvim (Japanized VIM)
vim-addon-manager - manager of addons for the Vim editor
vim-gtk - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GTK2 GUI
vim-latexsuite - view, edit and compile LaTeX documents from within Vim
vim-nox - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
vim-scripts - plugins for vim, adding bells and whistles
vim-syntax-gtk - Syntax files to highlight GTK+ keywords in vim
vim-vimoutliner - script for building an outline editor on top of Vim
vim-common - Vi IMproved - Common files
vim-dbg - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor (debugging symbols)
vim-doc - Vi IMproved - HTML documentation
vim-gnome - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GNOME2 GUI
vim-gui-common - Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
vim-runtime - Vi IMproved - Runtime files
vim-tiny - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
vim-rails - plugins for vim to allow easier editing of Rails Applications
```

Comment: You can use apt-cache search -n vim to search only package names instead of piping the output into grep

Comment: As was noted by @Johan (but to make it more obvious) on some older versions of Ubuntu there was a package called vim-full which could be installed.

Comment: Afterwards You may need to change the link from /usr/bin/vim.tiny to /usr/bin/vim.full

Use whereis vim to get more information

Answer (score 11):

This is what I usually install:

```
sudo apt-get install vim vim-scripts vim-doc vim-latexsuite vim-gui-common vim-gnome
```

In the past, there used to be a package called "vim-full"...

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-vim
sudo apt-get install gnome-vim
```