# What ever happened to vim-full package that used to be available in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vim

Why was it removed and is there a way to get it? I know about [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/127292/how-to-install-vim-full-in-ubuntu) but I am curious as to why it would have been removed?

Also if you do an install like this:

```
apt-get install vim vim-scripts vim-doc vim-latexsuite vim-gui-common vim-gnome
```

What is actually happening? Are there different versions of vim installed or does it compile vim with all those options or ...???

Sorry about the multiple questions here but it would seem silly to break them out into individual questions since they are all very related.

BTW I am using 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been replaced by vim-gnome.  Packages often get renamed between releaases.  This change has been in the works since Hardy.

From Jaunty "This package is simply a transitional package from vim-full to vim-gnome."

Found on [Ubuntu pacakges list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/vim-full)

Answer (score 1):

`vim-full` was replaced by `vim-gnome`. See BillThor's answer for a bit more specifics.

vim is broken down into sub packages: `vim` is the core binary, `vim-scripts` are some extra scripts related to vim, `vim-doc` is the documentation for vim, `vim-gui-common` is common components for the graphical interface to vim, and `vim-gnome` is the gnome-specific application for launching a GUI version of vim.

These are broken down because not everyone wants all of these components. If I only work from the command line and already know how to use vim (or any other application), then the *-gui-common and *-gnome and *-doc packages make for a lot of wasted space and time downloading them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Follow on question: If I want to get the perl, python, tcl and ruby I can just keep adding the sub-packges and it should work fine?

Comment: @stephenmm Generally you only install what you need. If you want the command line interpreters, then install `perl`, `python`, `tcl`, and `ruby`. These will include the executables and standard libraries. If you need specific submodules, install as needed. (like `libapache2.2-perl` (I think?) if you want perl module for apache).

The best way to list submodules is with something like `apt-get install .*perl.*`. You shouldn't blindly install all of these unless you need them, however. Otherwise, it just wastes space.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant to say was that If I need the python-enabled version of vim and the the perl-enbaled version of vim and ... I can just "apt-get install vim-perl vim-python vim-ruby vim-tcl"? I use a lot of vim plugins and different plugins require all these to be enabled.

Comment: Yes, you can, assuming those are the names of the packages. You can use `apt-cache`'s `search` option to list all packages that start with `vim`, or just try `apt-get install vim-.*` - It'll ask to confirm which packages to install.